# How do I stack two photos in Photoshop to reduce noise?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photoshop, noise-reduction, image-stacking

I tried stacking two pictures in Photoshop to create a final image with less noise. But I ended up with a pic that had *more*. Is there any other way to stack two pictures so that there is less noise?

Can I stack two pictures in Lightroom instead of Photoshop?

Comment: Is your goal to reduce noise, or is it to do something else, but you are noticing that in the process of doing that, you are getting increased noise?

Comment: I want to stich two pics with reduced noise ... but when I stich there is an increase in noise ! How do I deal with it ? @mattdm

Comment: Stacking images would normaly reduce noise, but if you use the wrong method it could increase the noise. What method are you using?

Comment: Placing one image on the other , then using blending options . @Guffa

Answer (score 4):

You can also use an median blending (create image stack and apply the "Median" stack mode)

- File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack
- Select all layers and use Edit > Auto Align to align them (if necessary)
- Layer > Smart Objects > Convert to Smart Object
- Layer > Smart Objects > Stack Mode and choose Median

Discussion of this and other methods here:

[Does median blending / image stacking result in better or worse results than a long exposure?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45434/4191)

Answer (score 2):

When you stack images for the purpose of noise reduction, you shouldn't use blending.

Use opacity to mix the layers to get the average:

```
Layer 1   50%
Layer 2  100%
```

For more layers you use an opacity of 1/3, 1/4, 1/5 etc.:

```
Layer 1   20%
Layer 2   25%
Layer 3   33%
Layer 4   50%
Layer 5  100%
```